# Why do some recently asked questions not show up in the question list?

Tags: support, interesting-page

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287536/getcursorpos-only-returning-x-value), but within minutes, it was off the question list even though the question list went back an hour in time.

Is this some form of moderation?  If so, it seems weird that no comment was made within the thread that the question was deleted, moved, or otherwise removed from the question list.

Comment: No moderation action makes questions "disappear" like that. If it was deleted (the only thing that makes it disappear from the list) the link wouldn't work anymore (for non-10k rep users) and it would disappear from your list of questions.

Comment: There 17 views on it. I gave it a bump for you.

Comment: @Mysticial Very strange.  It still doesn't show up for me.  I don't get how StackOverflow software works.  :S  Did they make a change where questions asked by a user do not show up in the question list for that user?  So weird...

Comment: Are one of the tags on your "ignored" list? Anyways, either my bump or this post has attracted some attention. You have two answers now.

Comment: @Mysticial I have no ignored tags.  I see the new answers... thanks for the bump!  :D  PS: Interestingly enough, now that the question is answered, it is appearing on the question list.

Comment: Possibly related to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/, if you're referring to the homepage

Comment: @waiwai933 thanks, I wondered myself about the algorithm and never saw that blog post!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138366/why-do-some-recently-asked-questions-not-show-up-in-the-question-list#comment389036_138366) and taken from [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) by Jeff, here is the algorithm that decide what question appear in the *Interesting* view which is the default of Stack Overflow homepage:

> Here’s how it works. Starting with a list of the last 3,000 active
> questions:
>
> - drop questions containing any of your ignored tags
> - drop closed questions if you lack the reputation required to vote for reopening
> - drop questions scoring -4 or lower
>
> Next, apply the following score formula to the remaining questions:
>
> your [interesting tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/)
>             
> +1,500 per interesting tag, up to +2,000 total
>
> your top 40 scoring tags       maximum of
> +1,000 per tag (scaled), up to +2,000 total
>
> question score
>                     
> +200 × score, up to +1,000 total
>
> total answer score
>                
> -200 × score, up to -1,000 total
>
> number of answers
>              
> -200 × answers, up to -1,000 total
>
> number of views
>                   
> -15 × views, up to -1,000 total
>
> question last activity date       -1 ×
> (seconds / 15)
>
> Count it all up and take the top 90 by score.

So in your case, I would guess you have favorite tags other than those you chose for your own question thus questions with those tags jumped to the top, leaving your own question behind.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, as I have no ignored or favorite tags.  I don't think I've ever answered a vb6-tagged question, though, so it wasn't in my "top 40 scoring tags."  It seems like there should be an exception for questions that you yourself asked, though!

Comment: @Michael yep maybe same way questions are dropped, questions you asked should always appear. :)