# Why I can't see question with the right tags?

Tags: support, tags

Just created [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225386/should-i-namespace-sti-models) question on stackoverflow and at first, I was not able to see my question at all from the stack root page.

I had to add to my favorite tags: `sti` and `namespaces`

Why is that ? I should see the question already since I have `ruby`, `ruby-on-rails` on my favorite tags.

I double check my blacklisted tags and none of them are blacklisted.

Comment: You were not able to see it where? From the search results? It takes a few minutes before new questions show up in a search, thanks to caching. How quickly after posting did you try looking? Can you see it *now* if you remove those tags from your favorites?

Comment: from my stackoverflow dashboard http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default view of Stack Overflow homepage is the *[interesting view](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting)* which is unique to Stack Overflow and using special formula to show questions that are more likely to interest you, based on your favorite tags and more parameters.

So many questions are indeed not included on that view.

To see all questions, go to the *[questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)* where you can sort by newest or active, and your question appears there just fine:

> [image]

The formula is quoted and explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138382/152859) in other answer I wrote a while ago.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm just wondering that if I can't see it from the "interesting view", do other people can't see it too if their tags are not "complete" ?

Comment: @Pierre anyone with [tag:ruby] as favorite tag should see it just fine, but those without any favorite tags will see mostly questions that receive lots of views and votes in a short while, non of which apply in your case. :/

Comment: Ok thank you for your help.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois It's more complex that just favorite tags: [the home page is based on some complex statistical analysis](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow/). If the home page showed [every new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), it would roll over every 10 minutes on average. If it showed [every edited thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) that would be about 3 minutes.

Comment: @Gilles true, but favorite tag score is much higher, overriding the other parameters.