# Old posts showing up as current when updates made

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Seems like any post that gets edited gets it's timestamp updated to time of edit on main page listing. Just saw this post from 2012 at top of list due to a new answer. I sure don't remember this behavior in the past

[jquery colorbox bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720102/jquery-colorbox-bottom)

Comment: I'm pretty certain that's normal behavior. Try clicking other questions on the main page- any that have been edited will show the edited time. (Which makes sense as a behavior- the editing is what bumped it to the main page in the first place)

Comment: @DavidRobinson maybe it's just me...but I don't remember ever seeing ancient stuff get bumped up when someone throws in their 2 cents worth a year later...let alone post made many hours ago get bumped up

Comment: This is how the site has always worked, by design. If you don't want this behaviour, look for the "newest" tab.

Comment: ahhah  @JeremyBanks  ...has there been a design change in the last few months... I get no more `newest` tab on home page...defaults to `interesting`...and flakes answering year old stuff isn't very interesting

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - you need to click "questions", then click "newest". Most pages though take you directly to "questions" instead of the homepage.

Comment: ok..maybe I'm going senile.... have clicked the main logo link for as long as I've been here.... just seems odd I'm seeing old posts

Comment: The "interesting" tab is unique to Stack Overflow and show questions based on [complicated formula](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138382/152859). As you see, it's starting with "last 3,000 active questions" and the last factor is "question last activity date". Editing a question or one if its answers means setting its "last activity" timestamp to the time of edit.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned in the comments, [the "interesting" tab on the home page has been around for a long time](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/). Additionally, every non-Stack Overflow site in the network defaults to sorting by activity (in the reverse chronological order), so every Stack Exchange home page shows you questions that recently had something happen to them - typically an answer or an edit.

What you're looking for is the "newest" sub-tab on the "Questions" page instead. (Note that we also (somewhat unfortunately) remember which sub-tab on /questions you visit last and default to that on future visits.)

You can bookmark [/questions?sort=newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), although you might want to further restrict that by tag since Stack Overflow gets thousands of questions every day.

Comment: thanks anna...I'm not as young as I used to be...but I'm certainly not a rookie with regard to answering questions, or knowing my habits when using the site( which certainly includes using tags). Always found the main logo link easiest and laziest  clcik point, I'll just script it to change it's href to "/questions"...sorry to bother anyone...it just felt different